# End of file syntax error shell scripting

Tags: bash, scripts

```
#!/bin/bash

source conf.ini

inotifywait -m -e create /$1path |
  while read file; do

if ($(echo $word | head -c 1)"=$1 then
    echo $file
cd $1inputpath
ls -l |grep $file*
zcat $file* > /tmp/$file
sort /tmp/$file > /tmp/$file.sorted
cd $1outputpath
 ls -l |grep $file
sort  $file > /tmp/$file.origsorted
diff /tmp/$file.origsorted  /tmp/$file.sorted
 if [ $? -eq 0 ];
 then
   echo OK
else
echo FAIL
echo $file
fi

fi
      done
```

I get below error:en do fthe file:

```
./FoldersegCompare: line 8: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./FoldersegCompare: line 32: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Answer (score 2):

In don't know what you are trying to do with this script but looking at it first time i see the errors are because of this line :

```
if ($(echo $word | head -c 1)"=$1 then
```

Make it as :

```
if [ "$(echo $word | head -c 1)" = "$1" ]; then
```

while doing a check with `if-then` conditional construct use `test` (`[`) or `[[` (`bash`-ism). Check `help test` for more info.

When you are doing `if ($(echo $word | head -c 1)"=$1 then` :

- There are syntax errors, `(` after `if` and `"` before `=`, perhaps you meant `"$(echo $word | head -c 1)"`
- Also as you are using no `test` (or `[[`), the `=` simply suggests that you are doing a variable assignment. So you need `[` (`test`) or `[[` to make sure that you are comparing things
- Also you have missed a `;` before `then` which is a shorthand for newline (or you can put `then` at the next line)

Also your script seems inefficient (to be honest) to me by looking at the commands you have used to get the job (i don't know what) done. Perhaps you should go through the scripting answers posted here and other sites to get some idea about which tool to use in what situation, ask a new question to see what others suggest to solve your problem and of course use indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Correct the following issues and check your script again [here](http://www.shellcheck.net/) or see my corrections below

```
   1  #!/bin/bash
   2  
   3  source conf.ini
   4  
   5  inotifywait -m -e create /$1path |
   6    while read file; do
   7  
   8  if ($(echo $word | head -c 1)"=$1 then
          ^––SC1009 The mentioned parser error was in this simple command.
                                   ^––SC1073 Couldn't parse this double quoted string.
   9      echo $file
  10  cd $1inputpath
  11  ls -l |grep $file*
  12  zcat $file* > /tmp/$file
  13  sort /tmp/$file > /tmp/$file.sorted
  14  cd $1outputpath
  15   ls -l |grep $file
  16  sort  $file > /tmp/$file.origsorted
  17  diff /tmp/$file.origsorted  /tmp/$file.sorted
  18   if [ $? -eq 0 ];
  19   then
  20     echo OK
  21  else
  22  echo FAIL
  23  echo $file
  24  fi
  25  
  26  fi
  27        done
      ^––SC1072 Expected end of double quoted string. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```

E.G.

```
#!/bin/bash

source conf.ini

inotifywait -m -e create /"$1path" |
while read -r file; do
  if ("$(echo "$word" | head -c 1)"="$1"); then
    echo "$file"
    cd "$1inputpath" || exit
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "$file"
    zcat "$file"* > /tmp/"$file"
    sort /tmp/"$file" > /tmp/"$file".sorted
    cd "$1outputpath" || exit
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "$file"
    sort  "$file" > /tmp/"$file".origsorted
    diff /tmp/"$file".origsorted  /tmp/"$file".sorted
    if [ $? -eq 0 ];
    then
      echo OK
    else
      echo FAIL
      echo "$file"
    fi
  fi
done
```

---

And if you get something like this

```
./FoldersegCompare: line 5: inotifywait: command not found
```

simply install with

```
sudo apt-get install inotify-tools
```

Comment: That's too complex. Just tell him that there is a lonely `"` in line 8. ;-)

Comment: @Pilot6 ok, done =)

Comment: Yes that helped but i still get                                                                                                               ./FoldersegCompare: line 25: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
./FoldersegCompare: line 25: `fi'

Comment: @Testpriya in my script? That's not possible.

Comment: #!/bin/bash

source conf.ini

inotifywait -m -e create /$1path |
  while read file; do
if [ "$(echo $word | head -c 1)" = "$1" ];

    echo $file
cd $1inputpath
ls -l |grep $file*
zcat $file* > /tmp/$file
sort /tmp/$file > /tmp/$file.sorted
cd $1outputpath
 ls -l |grep $file
sort  $file > /tmp/$file.origsorted
diff /tmp/$file.origsorted  /tmp/$file.sorted
 if [ $? -eq 0 ];
 then
   echo OK
else
 echo "FAIL"
 echo $file
  fi
fi
      done

Comment: I hav epasted in the text editor

Comment: Use my script. I can't parse your script as comment.

Comment: You forgot a `then` Use this line `if [ "$(echo $word | head -c 1)" = "$1" ];  then`

Comment: Thanks.And also i get ./FoldersegCompare: line 5: inotifywait: command not found

Comment: Can someone help with this.Do i need to call any libraries for inotifywait command to work?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install inotify-tools`

Comment: Don't thank me! ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green. If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow... If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: sudo: apt-get: command not found       I get this now

Comment: Hm, you don't have Ubuntu, right?

Comment: Yes i dont hav eubuntu...I am on REd hat linux server 6.5

Comment: Redhat and Ubuntu are different in details and therefore off-topic here. Please, be fair and accept my answer. For further question you should use the sister page Unix & Linux.